# Windows Task Scheduler won't run task based on RDP login event

Tags: remote-desktop, scheduled-tasks, windows-11

I want to run a command whenever I log in to my computer via RDP remote session. In task scheduler, I set the trigger as follows:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational">
    <Select Path="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational">*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=1149)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Then I tried logging in via RDP but the task won't be triggered at all, even though the event is logged.

```
Protokollname: Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational
Quelle:        Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager
Datum:         22.10.2021 16:01:32
Ereignis-ID:   1149
Aufgabenkategorie:Keine
Ebene:         Informationen
Schlüsselwörter:
Benutzer:      Netzwerkdienst
Computer:      My Computer Name
Beschreibung:
Remotedesktopdienste: Die Benutzerauthentifizierung war erfolgreich:

Benutzer: My ID
Domäne: 
Quellnetzwerkadresse: My IP
Ereignis-XML:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager" Guid="{c76baa63-ae81-421c-b425-340b4b24157f}" />
    <EventID>1149</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>0</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x1000000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2021-10-22T14:01:32.8354266Z" />
    <EventRecordID>1034</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{f42073e2-bc36-4f11-bcee-f01056750000}" />
    <Execution ProcessID="2024" ThreadID="8216" />
    <Channel>Microsoft-Windows-TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager/Operational</Channel>
    <Computer>My Computer</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-20" />
  </System>
  <UserData>
    <EventXML xmlns="Event_NS">
      <Param1>My User ID</Param1>
      <Param2>
      </Param2>
      <Param3>My IP</Param3>
    </EventXML>
  </UserData>
</Event>
```

I thought the issue my come from the read permission of IDs but running this task as SYSTEM or as my own account (on background) won't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using the wrong event id, that you should use
Event id 20521, defined as
"User config info will be loaded from local machine for this RDP-Tcp connection":

- Open Event Viewer
- Go to
  *Applications and Services Logs > Microsoft > Windows >
  TerminalServices-RemoteConnectionManager > Admin*
- Any event with ID=20521 is a successful RDP connection
- Right-Click on the event and select "Attach task to this event".

Comment: Thanks, the issue I had is that although I do have the correct event ID, the login event in TerminalServices-RemoteConnection-Operation is not automatically protocolled. The event I used for trigger will only be there if it's enabled in gpedit.msc